# Array and base address redirection

Tags: c, arrays

```
int a[10];
printf("%p ", &a);
```

will display the address of array `a`.

So, if I perform a redirection, `*(&a)`, why is that I don't get value stored at `a[0]`. What is the rule in C language that states I should be getting address of `a`. Yes, it does make sense, I get address of `a`, since `*` and `&` will cancel each other leading to simply `a`, which is the address of `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C rule that governs this is C 2011 6.3.2.1 3: “Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, the _Alignof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.”

`a` is an array of int. When you pass `a` to printf, the rule converts it to a pointer to int, and the value of that pointer is printed.

When you pass `&a` to printf: First, `a` is the operand of `&`, so the rule does not apply; `a` is not converted to a pointer to int; it remains an array of int. Second, the `&` is evaluated. `&a` yields the address of the array, and this address is printed. Since the address of the array is the same as the address of its first element, the address is printed.

Note that the type of the expression `&a` is “pointer to array of int”. So, when you have `*&a`, you are applying `*` to a pointer to an array of int, and the result is an array of int. Since the expression is an array of int, the rule applies, and this array of int is converted to a pointer to the first element, and the value of that pointer is printed.

Answer (score 2):

```
int a[10];
printf("%p ", (void *) &a);  // address of the array
printf("%p ", (void *) a);   // adress of the first element of the array
printf("%p ", (void *) *(&a));// same as above
```

Here, the value of `a` is the same as `&a[0]`. And the value `*&a` is the same as the value of `a` when the `a` object is an array of `int`.

Note that the printed address will be the same as they both start at the same address.

I added the `void *` cast which is required as `p` requires a `void *` argument.

Comment: This states what happens without answering the asker’s question of what the rule is.

Answer (score 0):

The fact:

```
a[0] == *(a)
a[9] == *(a+9)
```

Comment: This does not explain why `*&a` has the same value as `&a`. In the absence of knowledge of the special C rule that transforms arrays into pointers, it is surprising that `*&a` has the same value as `&a` when `*a` does not have the same value as `a`.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the pointer that `&a` evaluates to is a pointer to an array (specifically a pointer to an `int[10]`).  That's a different type that a pointer to the first element of the array, even if it's the same address.

`printf("%d ", *&a[0]);` will print the value of the first element of the array because  `&a[0]` has type `int*`.